# use the Pseudoclassical instantiation after ajax

Tags: javascript

I have a Pseudoclassical instantiation declared before ajax. How can I use it again after the ajax call?

```
var x = new plupload.Uploader({
  init: {
    //codes
  }
})
```

How can I use the var x inside the ajax call? For example `x.init();`

p.s
I thought it is function expression

Comment: x().foo() .. x is a function

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you will not be able to do x.foo() since the variable x will contain a function that will return an object with the methods you want to use. So in order to use the foo function, you need to call the x first to retrieve an object.

```
var obj = x();
obj.foo();
```

Or you could just create an object in x without wrapping it into a function and then use it like x.foo();

```
var x = {
  foo: function() { some code here },
  bar: function() { some code here },
};
x.foo();
```

Comment: Im sorry I think my question is misleading please see the new edit. It was instantiated class instead of function expression.